# How to add firebase rules for updating data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

To add rules for new data, I'm using .validate and newData. This rule works fine when I'm adding new data.
However when i'm updating data at the existing location, the rules dont work.
Please help.
Below is the rule set:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "User":{".validate":"newData.child('weight').isNumber() && newData.child('weight').val()>=1 && newData.child('weight').val()<=300"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/ check out the .write rules. If you could provide some more information, maybe someone could help.

Comment: Would you mind providing the data and location you are trying to update?

Comment: Saying "the rules don't work" is very vague. What exactly isn't working? What errors are you getting? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens. What are you trying to do/write?

Comment: I'm trying to write(update) an existing User node. I entered a string value for weight and it still writes. According to the rule, weight can be only number.

Comment: However, when I try to add a new User, with weight as String, it denies write- it workd perfectly.

Comment: In addition to your rules, can you also show the write operation that is failing?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "User":{
            "width" : {
                ".validate":"newData.child('weight').isNumber() && newData.child('weight').val()>=1 && newData.child('weight').val()<=300",
            },
            "$other" : {
                ".validate":false
                }
            }
  }
}
```

if we look at the documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data

> The predefined data variable is used to refer to the data before a write operation takes place. Conversely, the newData variable contains the new data that will exist if the write operation is successful. **newData represents the merged result of the new data being written and existing data.**

if there is already registered data

```
{
    "width" : 50
}
```

newData

```
{
    "height" : 100
}
```

actually newData [merged data]

```
{
    "width" : 50,
    "height" : 100
}
```

".validate" doesn't work for this reason

sorry for english